# Est-ce que «Je n’ai pas la même opinion de l’honnêteté aujourd’hui qu’autrefois » est correct?

Tags: choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, constructions, formulation-idiomatique

J’hésite entre l’énonciation concernée et «Je n’ai pas la même opinion de l’honnêteté aujourd’hui que celle que j’avais autrefois »?

La phrase citée en question est-elle correcte sur le plan syntaxique? Selon ma manière de voir les deux phrases, la première mettrait en opposition deux temps différents (aujourd’hui et autrefois) alors que la seconde, l’opinion (conception) à deux temps différents - opinion présente et opinion passée -, est-ce ma façon de voir est juste ou non?

Merci!

Comment: *Autrefois* = « À une époque appartenant à un passé révolu » — *Auparavant* (ou *qu'avant*) : « Adv. de temps marquant l'antériorité dans le temps d'un fait par rapport à un autre. » *Autrefois* renvoie en effet au passé, par forcément lointain, mais marque une évolution dans la pensée du locuteur, une prise de conscience des imperfections des pensées passées. *Auparavant* s'utilisera plutôt après une démonstration : grâce à cette information, ma  conception du problème a évolué.

Comment: @Personne J’ai mal exprimé la seconde phrase dans les détails: j’ai écrit « auparavant » mais il fallait lire « autrefois ». La question porte sur la tournure de la phrase, ce qui introduit « que ». Merci.

Comment: Ma question s’apparente drôlement aux difficultés rencontrées dans des constructions comme Ce concurrent a un problème de gestion aussi grave que moi ou Ce concurrent a un problème de gestion aussi grave que le mien?

Comment: « Ce concurrent a un problème de gestion aussi grave que *moi* » → moi = problème ! Vous vous identifiez à un problème, ou bien un problème possède votre esprit (un esprit vous manipule :-)  … on peut digresser, mais dans ce contexte, c'est un choix erroné. « Ce concurrent a un problème de gestion aussi grave que le mien » est beaucoup plus cohérent : identité des situations de deux personnes face à un problème identique (et non : une personne face à un problème <#> un problème identifié par une personne) — mais cela n'a rien à voir avec *autrefois* que l'on peut substituer par *auparavant*.

Comment: … selon l'intention/la situation que l'on veut exprimer … en enlevant le faux problème de l'indispensable que … la suite en commentaire de la réponse de @jiliagre https://french.stackexchange.com/a/45204/848

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La phrase proposée dans le titre de la question est probablement correcte syntaxiquement mais assez lourde et difficile à comprendre au premier abord.

La deuxième passe mieux, mais je la remanierais comme ceci :

> Je n'ai pas aujourd'hui la même opinion que celle que j'avais il y a quelques années à propos de l'honnêteté.

voire même, plus directement :

> Mon opinion sur l'honnêteté a changé.

Comment: « que celle que j’avais » remplacé par « qu' » est pour moi la formule plus facile à dire, la plus concise, la plus instinctive pour densifier une réponse orale … peut être une question de paresse, pour faire plus avec moins de moyens … la seconde est lourdingue (gnangnan, celle bon élève chouchou de la maîtresse d'école :-), mais possible dans une réponse qui est destinée à un public varié. — « Mon opinion sur l'honnêteté a changé. » est une belle contraction de texte … pourtant elle ne véhicule pas la même implication du locuteur, il y a comme une affirmation qui ne peut être discutée …

Comment: … du genre « et je me moque de ce que tu en penses » (cela est dû à ce que la contraction de texte est magnifiée dans les textes de loi : « Tout condamné à mort aura la tête tranchée. » [obsolète de nos jours en France], là aussi aucun mot ne peut être enlevé, c'est une assertion, un axiome irréfutable) alors que la première invite l'auditeur à questionner l'évolution … … … cette impression peut ne pas être du tout partagée :-)

Comment: @Personne Oui, *que j'avais* est moins soutenu et plus concis, mais tant qu'à faire concis, autant pousser jusqu'à ma deuxième suggestion qui pour moi ne ferme pas plus la porte à la discussion. Si mon opinion n'est pas la même, c'est bien qu'elle a changé après tout.